# Span inside Action Link

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use bootstrap span icon in Action link

here is examples

```
$actions .= "<a href='" . $this->url->link('seller/account-product/delete', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'], 'SSL') ."' class='btn btn-primary btn-danger' title='" . $this->language->get('ms_delete') . "'></a>";
```

and i want to add this into

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `'` instead of `"`

```
$actions .= "<a href='" . $this->url->link('seller/account-product/delete', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'], 'SSL') ."' class='btn btn-primary btn-danger' title='" . $this->language->get('ms_delete') . "'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

When quoting gets hairy, I prefer to add a few helper variables to make the markup cleaner:

```
$l = $this->url->link('seller/account-product/delete', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'], 'SSL');
$c1 = 'btn btn-primary btn-danger';
$t = $this->language->get('ms_delete');
$c2 = 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove';

$actions .= "<a href='$l' class='$c1' title='$t'><span class='$c2'></span></a>";
```

or, depending on how you read the question:

```
$actions .= "<span class='$c2'><a href='$l' class='$c1' title='$t'></a></span>";
```

Sometimes, it is beneficial to be even more consice:

```
$h  = " href='"
    . $this->url->link('seller/account-product/delete', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id'], 'SSL')
    . "'";
$c1 = " class='btn btn-primary btn-danger'";
$t  = " title='" . $this->language->get('ms_delete') . "'";
$c2 = " class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'";

$actions .= "<a$h$c1$t><span$c2></span></a>";
```